# DropDownList selects top value only

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, copy

I have a textbox that will be filled by a button click.
When i Click the button, it will compare some values and then copy the value from a dropdownlist it to the first textbox.

But the dropdownlist only copies the first value, even if i select a second or third value, it will always copy the first.

Here is my code:

```
protected void BtnOrderKoppelen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(DDLLijnRequest.Text == "Lijn1")
        {
            TbProd5.Text = DDLVrijgeefOrder.Text;
        }

        else if (DDLLijnRequest.Text == "Lijn2")
        {
            TbProd6.Text = DDLVrijgeefOrder.Text;
        }

        else if (DDLLijnRequest.Text == "Lijn3")
        {
            TbProd7.Text = DDLVrijgeefOrder.Text;
        }

        else if (DDLLijnRequest.Text == "Lijn4")
        {
            TbProd8.Text = DDLVrijgeefOrder.Text;
        }

    }
```

DDLLijnRequest= a dropdownlist for my production line comparison

TbProd(5 till 8) = are textboxes where data from DDLVrijgeefOrder has to go to

DDLVrijgeefOrder = a dropdownlist where i select an order and want it to copy to the textboxes.

Is there a way that it could copy any value that i have selected in DDLVrijgeefOrder?

This is my pageload, it has no connection yet with the button click or the dropdownlist. Do i have to add something here? :

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["MesLogin"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("StartPagina.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            LblSession.Text = "Welcome" + Session["MesLogin"].ToString();
        }

    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: show your `Page_Load`

Comment: Added it to the question, im pretty new with asp.net so didnt know that it could have impact on my dropdownlists.

Comment: I would potentially use a switch statement and avoid using "magic strings" in you code - make this private readonly consts at the top of file - this wont fix your issue but would clean up the code

Comment: @rico how are you binding your dropdown and where ?

Comment: @Webruster im using visual studio and it gives the option to bind them with my database with a button click. I generates my connection code in html with my sqldatasource connection.

Comment: @RicoBrouwer try to bind your dropdown in `!isPostback` in `PageLoad`

Comment: @webruster was already trying that and worked fine now :) I just had to bind my data from a datasource in my c# code to the DDL in the page load and it worked.

Comment: @RicoBrouwer glad it works

Answer (score 1):

Hope you bind the drop-down value all the time in Page_load event. Drop down data source should be binded only in very first time otherwise it will always bind to first value.

Example:

```
Void Page_Load()
{
  if(!IsNotPostBack)
  {
    // bind drop down values here
  }
}
```

If the above solution doesn't help, please post some more code like Page_Load event

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context of your question you are using WinForms right?

The following link provides a good answer to your question:

[How to create a drop down menu in WinForms and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723668/how-to-create-a-drop-down-menu-in-winforms-and-c-sharp)

> Note that you can add any type of item to the ComboBox. If you don't
>   specify the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties, the ComboBox
>   uses the ToString method of the object in order to determine the text
>   displayed and you can retrieve the selected item (not selected value)
>   through the SelectedItem property.

```
class Person
{
 public int PersonID { get; set }
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }

 public override string ToString()
 {
     return FirstName + " " + LastName;
 }
}
```

Eventually you can do

```
Person selectedPerson = (Person)myComboBox.SelectedItem;
int personID = selectedPerson.PersonID;
```

Comment: I am using asp.net, but will give a look at this!