# How to remove an item from dropdownlist control in c#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a dropwdown list with few items like this(in the format "name-number"):

```
     George Michael - 456456
     Justin Dukes - 5644654
     Peter Heins - 5456454
     Mark Twain - 4454564
```

Now i have to delete an item from the above list based on the value i have from other query.

My other query gives me a number in string format and i have to remove exactly the same item which is in the above dropdownlist second part(after hyphen).

For ex: My query gives me "5456454".

Now I have to remove the third item(Peter Heins - 5456454) from the dropdownlist  which matches with the number my query returns.

I am trying to use

```
ddl.Items.Remove
```

But Im not getting what parameter i should pass. Both the text and value fields are same in the dropdownlist and i cannot modify that. So i cannot use

```
ddl.Items.FindByValue()
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you populating your dropdown control ? Are you using datasource binding (if not, you should) - have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723668/how-to-create-a-drop-down-menu-in-winforms-and-c-sharp

Comment: I am adding items through a for loop not a datasource binding.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use data binding - it will make your life a lot easier when it comes to doing this sort of searching operation and is more maintainable. BTW i'm assuming this is Winforms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var removeItem = ddl.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                          .Where(x => x.Value.Contains(number))
                          .FirstOrDefault()

ddl.Items.Remove(removeItem);
```

Comment: Thanks much. This worked. But now I have a question. As Contains works as Substring, it may delete other ones also. Like the following scenario:

Comment: Abcd-123<br/>fghdg-456123<br/>jhghg-7989

Comment: Now if i check Contains(123) it will delete first and second also. Right?

Comment: @Santosh - no, it will take the first item that matches. I'm assuming the number you would pass in would be unique?

Answer (score 1):

If you're populating your DropDownList with ListItem objects, I would set the text for example to "Peter Heins - 5456454" and the value to "5456454".

```
     ListItem exampleItem = new ListItem("Peter Heins - 5456454", "5456454");
```

Then, you could do as you described and call

```
     string value = "5456454";
     ListItem valueToRemove = ddl.Items.FindByValue(valueToRemove);
     dd1.Remove(valuetoRemove);
```

**edit:** If you absolutely cannot change the value (whether it be for school purposes or some other reason) I would do something like this.

```
        string id = "5456454";
        foreach (ListItem item in dd1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Text.Contains(id))
            {
                dd1.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, that's what i mentioned. I cannot change value filed of dropdown. Both text and value fields are same(name-number)

Comment: Edited my answer. Hopefully it helps solve your issue.