# using C# how do i set variables using a Form?

Tags: c#, forms, variables

```
            string Athlete_Year = "2019-20"; // 2019-20, ALL, 2018-20
            string Athlete_Division = "I"; // I , II, III
            string Athlete_Sport = "Women's Cross Country"; // "Men's Cross Country" , "Men's Track, Indoor" , "Men's Track, Outdoor" , "Women's Cross Country" , "Women's Track, Indoor" , "Women's Track, Outdoor"
            string Number_Of_Results = "500 rows";  // 10, 25, 50, 500
            string Athlete_Name = "Ashley Smith";
           //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               private void BtnDivision1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                 {
                          LblDivision.Text = "I";
                 }
//set for a button, i don't know how to use drop down options
```

I have a set of variables that work in my program. if i want to change the variables for example "Number_Of_Results" i need to manually do it within the code. im now learning how to use a form interface and was wondering how do i set one of these variables to one of the other options based on the form selections?

sorry I'm new to this.

For example i made a drop down box where you can select 10, 25, 50, and 500

once one of the options are selected how do i make the variable change to the selected  amount.

BONUS: from there how do i make a Start button to run the code.  i originally made the code for this program to run in a console app. is there a way to copy paste the source code from the console base one and embed it into a Start button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a dropdown menu in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723668/)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform these tasks from Events. Check out this site for more information on Events.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event

Coming back to your questions, For Combo box use the following event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged?view=netcore-3.1.

You can subscribe to the SelectedValueChanged and SelectedIndexChanged events and change the variable values in the Event handler.

For start button click, use the following event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=netcore-3.1

Use the button.click event on the start button to run your start code.

Comment: If this answer helped you. Please mark it as an answer.